# rsync with filter to include only certain file types for specific directory trees

Tags: command-line, rsync, synchronization, syntax

my rsync command looks like this:

```
rsync --update -rav --filter="merge $HOME/mergefilter.txt" ~/ (remote_destination):~/
```

My mergefilter.txt file looks like this:

```
+ /directory_1/***
+ /directory_2/***
+ /directory_etc/***
- /**
```

The `rsync` command works great and updates everything in the specified directory trees. However, I am looking to add some specifics to it. I am not sure of the necessary syntax, but for one of my directory trees, I want to only include certain files. For example, imagine my mergefilter.txt working like this:

```
+ /directory_1/***
+ /directory_2/*** --include="*.c++" --include="*.h" 
+ /directory_etc/***
- /**
```

So that when syncing the directory_2 directory tree (and its subdirectories), only .c++ and .h files are updated.

I have viewed other stackexchange pages asking similar questions, but none of them demonstrate how to use `include` when using a filter file.  What would be the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 2):

You are already using `include`; each line that begins with `+` is an include rule; every line that begins with `-` is an exclude rule.

If you want to include only specific files within a certain directory, then you have to spell it out unfortunately. Your filter file becomes:

```
+ /dir_1/***
+ /dir_2/
+ /dir_2/**.c++
+ /dir_2/**.h
+ /dir_2/**/
- /dir_2/**
+ /dir_etc/***
- /*
```

First you have to ensure that `dir_2` is included: `+ /dir_2/`.

Next you include all `*.c++` and all `*.h` files within that `dir_2`; remember that `**` matches all characters including slash.

Next you also have to include all directories within `dir_2`: `+ /dir_2/**/` otherwise the files within subdirectories aren't found, as those subdirectories are excluded.

Finally exclude all other files.

Note that you can also use per-directory merge files, so rsync will check every directory for a given filename and if found, use that file as an additional filter for that directory. See the `-F` option in the manpage.

Comment: Can you please explain why you used `- /*`at the end? What is the difference between `- /*` and `- *`? Cheers.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy at that point we only want to exclude files and directories in the root that haven't already explicitly included.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't `- *` achieve the same result? With the -a parameter to rsync it will recurse through every sub-directory of the source dir and `- *` will delete everything that has not been explicitly included?