# rsync - What is the difference between using * and ** in the exclude directive?

Tags: linux, files, rsync, directory

Following on from my [other question about rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627949/rsync-only-certain-files-types-from-specified-sub-directories).

I am trying to understand how include/exclude directives use patterns to match against the names of files in a source directory to decide which are to be synced to a destination directory.

Apparently `*` does not match a directory separator, but `**` can match one (zero or more of them, to be precise). Can someone explain very clearly what that means with a few rsync commands?

**For example:**

Here is my source dir structure:

```
../openwrt
../openwrt/afile.txt
../openwrt/BackupOfSettings
../openwrt/BackupOfSettings/file1.txt
../openwrt/BackupOfSettings/file2.txt
../openwrt/BackupOfSettings/file3.tar.gz
../openwrt/BackupOfPackages
../openwrt/BackupOfImages
../openwrt/BackupOfImages/anotherfile.txt
../openwrt/BackupOfImages/yetanotherfile.jpg
```

My source and destination directories:

```
openWrtPath="/mnt/usb/openwrt/"  
ncpPath="/media/myCloudDrive/openwrt"
```

Example command:
This command will only sync files with extension: tar.gz from the 'BackupOfSettings' folder.

```
rsync -vvritn --include='BackupOfSettings/' --include='BackupOfSettings/*.tar.gz' --exclude='*' $openWrtPath $ncpPath
```

The above command recurses through each sub-dir of the source-dir and applies the include and exclude patterns on each file... so how would it ever "see" a directory separator?

Can someone give a scenario, maybe like the above, that demonstrates the `*` failing and the `**` succeeding in matching a directory separator?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's add a few directories and files to `BackupOfSettings` to test the setup:

```
mkdir -p "$openWrtPath"/BackupOfSettings/sub1/sub2
touch "$openWrtPath"/BackupOfSettings/file1.tar.gz
touch "$openWrtPath"/BackupOfSettings/sub1/file2.tar.gz
touch "$openWrtPath"/BackupOfSettings/sub1/sub2/file3.tar.gz
```

And we also add subdirectories `sub1` and `sub1/sub2` as includes to the command:

```
rsync -vvritn \
  --include='BackupOfSettings/' \
  --include='BackupOfSettings/sub1/' \
  --include='BackupOfSettings/sub1/sub2/' \
  --include='BackupOfSettings/*.tar.gz' \
  --exclude='*' "$openWrtPath" "$ncpPath"
```

This syncs `BackupOfSettings/file1.tar.gz`, `BackupOfSettings/sub1/` and `BackupOfSettings/sub1/sub2/`, but not any files inside the subdirectories as `*` doesn't match a `/`.

---

Now let's try `BackupOfSettings/**.tar.gz` as include:

```
rsync -vvritn \
  --include='BackupOfSettings/' \
  --include='BackupOfSettings/sub1/' \
  --include='BackupOfSettings/sub1/sub2/' \
  --include='BackupOfSettings/**.tar.gz' \
  --exclude='*' "$openWrtPath" "$ncpPath"
```

This includes all three `*.tar.gz` files. The `**` is similar to `*`, but also matches the directory separator `/` (of `sub1/` and `sub1/sub2/`).

Showing a `**` as exclude (as in the title of the question) is a bit difficult, because `--exclude='*'` excludes the first level below `"$openWrtPath"` which also means any subdirectories and files are already excluded (because the parent directory at level 1 is excluded). Using `**` wouldn't make a difference.

---

To include directory `BackupOfSettings` and any subdirectories below that directory, you could replace the above three directory includes with

```
--include='BackupOfSettings/' \
--include='BackupOfSettings/**/' \
```

or

```
--include='BackupOfSettings/***/' \
```

From `man rsync`:

```
[...]
o      a ’*’ matches any path component, but it stops at slashes.

o      use ’**’ to match anything, including slashes.

[...]

o      if the pattern contains a / (not counting a trailing /) or a "**", then it
       is  matched  against the full pathname, including any leading directories.
       If the pattern doesn’t contain a / or a "**",  then  it  is  matched  only
       against the final component of the filename.  (Remember that the algorithm
       is applied recursively so "full filename" can actually be any portion of a
       path from the starting directory on down.)

o      a trailing "dir_name/***" will match both the directory (as if "dir_name/"
       had been specified) and everything in the directory (as  if  "dir_name/**"
       had been specified).  This behavior was added in version 2.6.7.
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks Freddy. I get it now. I was focusing on the idea of something like `--exclude='**'` but I guess it wouldn't make sense to use it that way. Instead the power of `**`is when used in a directive designed to include or exclude something like an entire branch of a directory tree.

Answer (score -1):

The double asterisk can be interpreted by the shell as a special globbing character. See also `man bash`:

```
globstar
    If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match 
    all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  
    If the pattern is followed by  a  /, only directories and subdirectories match.
```

Comment: The question is specifically about its use in `rsync` filter patterns

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad!

Comment: anyway i think the explanation is same